# I need to simplifying a date time series in pandas from per second to per day representation of data captured throughout the day

Tags: date, machine-learning, timestamp, time-series, tensorflow2.0

[This image helps to describe exactly what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXBTV.png)

So basically i have a data series like in the picture. The values are records over about a month cutting through August to September. Records are taken every second. I need to simplify it such that i get each row representing just one day and the column data of each row show the Starting, Maximum, minimum and ending value (Just like a stock market recording). Each second captures data but i need to just have a representation per day as opposed to per second. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to split the timestamp to date and time we can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time
df['value'] = value
```

Now we can use the following code snippet to extract the starting, max, min, ending values.

```
starting = []
max = []
min = []
ending = []
for i in df['Dates']:
   max.append(df[df['Dates'] == i]['value'].max())
   min.append(df[df['Dates'] == i]['value'].min())
   starting.append(df[df['Dates'] == i]['value'].iloc[0])
   ending.append(df[df['Dates'] == i]['value'].iloc[-1])
```

Create a new DataFrame:

```
d = {'date':df['Dates'], 'starting':starting, 'max':max, 'min':min, 'ending':ending}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df1)
```